# Check if date x are older than some number of days

Tags: c#, datetime

This is my first project in C#. I need Check if date x are older than some number of days.

Example:

```
if ( THIS_IS_SAVED_DATE_5_DAYS_AGO < OLDER_THAN_5_DAYS ) {

// Do this if saved date is more than 5 days

}
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 23):

You could use the [`AddDays`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays(v=vs.110).aspx) method to construct a new date relative to the current date and then compare the two dates:

```
DateTime x = ...
if (x < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5)) 
{
    // x is older than 5 days
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like:

```
if (x < x.AddDays(-1*days)) {

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can subract the dates and check the difference (which is of type `TimeSpan`):

```
if ((DateTime.Now - THIS_IS_SAVED_DATE_5_DAYS_AGO).TotalDays < 5) {
    //Executed when not older than five days
}
```